# WOrflow Foundation Cancellation Handler

Tags: workflow-foundation

Cancellation Handler works good for Composite activities like CAG, Parallel activity.

I need to know what are the activities will be cancelled in Cancellation Handlers.

I have codeactivities in my parallel activities The activites are reseted in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities can only be canceled when they are executing. So by searching through the EnabledActivities collections for the ones with the status Executing you can see which can be canceled.